# Date Range in Twitter Bootstrap DatePicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Could't get date Range. My function is

```
function abc() {
    jQuery("#<%=txtBirthDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        startDate: '2010-12-31',
        endDate: '2020-12-31'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `maxDate` and `minDate` instead of `startDate` and `endDate`.

Comment: I have also used maxDate and minDate but nothing happened.

Comment: @user3848417 Perhaps you're not using the right date format? Try adding `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'`